# Update Nested Objects with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to update nested objects with Mongoose. But when I receive the request, it looks like this:

```
{
'example[apple]': 'false',
'example[pear]': 'false',
'example[banana]': 'false',
'example[orange]': 'false',
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
email: {
    type: String,
    index:true,
    unique: true,
},
example: {
  apple: {type:Boolean, default: true},
  banana: {type:Boolean, default: true},
  pear: {type:Boolean, default: true},
  orange: {type:Boolean, default: true}
}
```

And the object I am sending looks like this:

```
var formData = {
  example: {
    apple: false,
    banana: false,
    pear: false,
    orange: false
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: who is generating and posting the request ? is it you. The structure of your request and the mongoose model are not aligned with each other.

Comment: @satishchennupati I am generating and posting the request. How should the model be to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the request body 
    `{
    'example[apple]': 'false',
    'example[pear]': 'false',
    'example[banana]': 'false',
    'example[orange]': 'false',
    }` is a JSON object you can access: example.apple and so on.
exampleObject must be JSON object first.
From your model it seems example is attribute in the model so to update you have to options:
1- Is to update all documents by not providing the id of the document:
    `yourmodel.findAndUpdate({no thing here},exampleObject,callBack)`

2-Is to update by condition;preferred:
    `yourmodel.findAndUpdate(condition,exampleObject,callBack)`
condition can be =     `{_id:an id}`